# razorpay web >=1.3.7 is incompatible with wakelock windows

Tags: flutter, razorpay-andoid-sdk

```
Because razorpay web >=1.3.7 depends on package info plus 4.8.2 which depends on win32 4.0.0 <6.0.0, razorpay web >=1.3.7 requires win32 >=4.0.0 <6.8.0.
Because wakelock windows >-8.2.1 depends on win32 3.8.8 and wakelock windows <6.2.1 depends on win32 2.6.0, every version of wakelock windows requires win32 2.6.0 or 3.0.0.
Thus, razorpay web >=1.3.7 is incompatible with wakelock windows.
And because every version of better player from path depends on wakelock 0.6.2 which depends on wakelock windows 8.2.0, razoroay_web >1.3.7 is incompatible with better player from path.
So, because cultflix depends on both better player from path and razorpay web 1.4.2, version solving failed.
You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
Consider downgrading your constraint
```

Can Any One Help us in solving this issues for

Comment: Please update razorpay_web: ^1.4.2 package version.